# Invalid read of size 1 in while loop condition

Tags: c, valgrind

I recently inherited code, written in C, without any documentation. I've been working at optimizing and fixing it and I've come across this.

```
int  LookBack(char * Start, int Length, char *Ignore)
{
  char  LookBuffer[10];
  //while(Start[-1] && Length--) Start--; // Start[-1]. No idea what that is supposed to mean.
  while(Length > 0 && Start[0]){
    Start--;
    Length--;
  }
  strncpy(LookBuffer, Start, sizeof(LookBuffer));
  if(strcasestr(LookBuffer, Ignore)) {
    return(1);
  }
  return(0);
}
```

This function is used to determine if a substring is a certain distance in front of the string `Start`. For example, take the string `The designation is API RP 5L1` and `Start` is a pointer to `API RP 5L1`. So, if `Ignore = "The"` and `Length = 10`, the function will return `0`.

My Question

Valgrind gives me the `Invalid read of size 1` error because it is reading past the allocated memory at `while(Length > 0 && Start[0])`, or so I believe. Is there any way I can check that `Start[0]` is in allocated memory without doing an invalid read?

Comment: Without seeing the calling code, it's impossible to answer your question.  But it sure look like the code you posted is based on the assumption that the `char` value immediately before the start of a string will be a `\0` character, and that is one horribly incorrect assumption.  It's not even safe to assume that value can be read at all.

Comment: That wouldn't help you much. In most realistic cases, `Start[0]` will be in allocated memory, just memory that was allocated for something else entirely. The way `valgrind` catches this is by intentionally inserting dead space around allocations that aren't normally there.

Comment: Well, first you do `while(Length > 0 && Start[0]){Length--; Start--; }`. After it `Length == 0` or `start[0] = '\0'` - both situations for me mean the end of string. After that you reached the end of buffer, you read 10 bytes from `Start` in `strncpy(LookBuffer, Start, sizeof(LookBuffer));`. It makes no sense to me, I don't know what is the purpose of this function.

Comment: The use of `strncpy` is also broken because `lookBuffer` will typically not get nul-terminated, and so `strstr` will read past its end.  Basically, I think you should toss this out and start over.

Comment: @NateEldredge Maybe it is best to scrap this and switch to a regex idea instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C functions that are working with memory buffers, it is caller responsibility to pass valid pointers. There might be some platform-specific trick, but in terms of standard C there's no way, as well as for many platforms (for example just-freed memory is often indistinguishable from still allocated).

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `LookBack`, so it seems to be called in some string processing / tokenization process similar to strtok(), which insert some `\0` at the split point.

`while(Start[-1] && Length--) Start--;` 
Look at the position before Start[0], if it is not a `\0` string terminator. If it is not a `\0` go one back.

`while( (*(Start-1) != '\0') && (0 != (Length--))) Start--;`

So, after the while loop you actually get a "start"-pointer in the string passed by Start pointer without readjusting it by +1 to actually get the second string part.

In your replacement, you actually miss to advance the Start pointer afterwards, because now it is pointing to a `\0`, which ends a string, so your string functions will just see an string of strlen(Start) = 0.